# Trying to run ColdFusion 10 on Ubuntu 14 with apache2?

Tags: server, apache2

I have been using ColdFusion 10 with IIS7, and recently decided to move to Ubuntu. I have installed CF to run as a self-contained server.

I am trying to use wsconfig with to configure CF to work with apache2. I use the following command:

```
sudo /opt/coldfusion10/cfusion/runtime/bin/wsconfig -ws Apache -dir /etc/apache2/ -v
```

And I get the following error:

```
[bash4.3:apache2] sudo /opt/coldfusion10/cfusion/runtime/bin/wsconfig -ws Apache -dir /etc/apache2/ -v
command line: -ws Apache -dir /etc/apache2/ -v 
Could not find file /etc/bin/httpd
Using Apache binary /usr/sbin/httpd
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
/etc/apache2 is not a valid configuration directory for Apache
```

I am getting the above error message all the time. Checked CF doc on Adobe and it was no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ColdFusion 10 doesn't work with Apache 2.4.x so I had to upgrade to ColdFusion 11 and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `/usr/sbin/httpd` to `/usr/sbin/apache2`

Answer (score -1):

I got this error for a couple reasons. As @Kunal noted, older versions of ColdFusion don't work with Apache 2.4, so my solution was to downgrade to Apache 2.2. I also continued to have this error when I was trying to use Debian, but it was fixed when I moved to Ubuntu.